# Create Pivot table query with dynamic restrictions on WHERE clause in C#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access-2010

So I'm working on Visual Studio 2012 in C# using an MS Access 2010 Database, and wanted to make a year planification with some data of a table according to certain restrictions (those seen in the WHERE clause).
I had this query from Access all nicely ready to use in my C# program and then stumbled upon the issue that I can't use it because it's not a "Valid SQL instruction"

```
OleDbConnection l = OleDbConnectionDAO.createConnection();
DataTable dt;
l.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = l.CreateCommand();
string transform = "TRANSFORM Max( IIf([frequência calibração] Is Not Null,(Format(DateAdd('m',Val([frequência calibração]),[Data Saida]),'yyyy/mm')),'Faltam dados')) AS MaxProximaCalib";
string select = "SELECT Codigo, B_DSC AS Artigo, Marca_ AS Marca, Modelo, N_Serie";
string from = "FROM APP_Equipamento_Geral";
string where = "WHERE YEAR(DateAdd('m',Val([frequência calibração]),[Data Saida])) = " + ano + " AND [Descrição Serviço] like "+servico+ "";
string groupby = "GROUP BY APP_Equipamento_Geral.Codigo, APP_Equipamento_Geral.B_DSC, APP_Equipamento_Geral.Marca_," +
                    "APP_Equipamento_Geral.Modelo, APP_Equipamento_Geral.N_Serie, Year(DateAdd('m',Val([frequência calibração]),[Data Saida]))";
string pivot = "PIVOT  IIf([frequência calibração] Is Not Null,(Format(DateAdd('m',Val([frequência calibração]),[Data Saida]),'yyyy/mm')),'Faltam dados');";
string query = transform + select + from + where + groupby + pivot;

cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, l);

dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
```

Is there a simpler way to run this query without resorting to going throughout [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa172756%28SQL.80%29.aspx)?

EDIT: TRANSFORM Added.

Comment: Have you tried `string transform = "TRANSFORM Max( ...`?

Comment: @GordThompson Yeah, he gives me "Syntax Error on TRANSFORM". Tried it in Access and it runs perfectly with the TRANSFORM, but not in visual studio with that error.

Comment: If you print out the query in the console - It will show that there is no spaces between the FROMWHERE etc. You need to add an space at the end of each string variable

Comment: @JamesReeves Seems like that was the issue. Thanks.